# Shortcut to attach debugger in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, android-debugging

I know we can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to detach the debugger but is there a shortcut to attach debugger in android studio?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a mapping for it in Android Studio:

Preferences > Keymap > Search for 'Attach debugger' or navigate the tree to: Main menu > Run > Attach debugger to Android process.

Then just add your preferred mapping. I think it's none on a fresh install of studio. Good luck!

Comment: I wish there could be and option to remember the device and auto attach the debuggers just like we have at the time of running the app. Anyways thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

in Android studio's toolbar there is a Attach Debugger Shortcut, shown in the image (poorly edited in MS Paint) .